# Laravel show date of post and other

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know if someone know how I can show date of post? For example if post was posted 12/12/2020 for it's shown posted: 12/12/2020.

Someone have little idea how I can? Help noob, I try something from other post in stackoverflow but it's not worked. And my seconde question, it's if someone have idea how I can do graphic in admin panel number of sell from website. So that the post has a lifespan of 1 month and that with a button republish this reissues, I create modify it delete and I would like to make a button to reissue.

Comment: Look into the `date()` function.

Comment: <p>Date: {{ $post->created_at }}</p> 
i do this worked but need other functions nox XD

Comment: Show your code since you seem to have some. Update your question (above) with your relevant code. You will find that doing that will allow people to take your question seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to format your date in blade, then you can do following :

```
{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($post->created_at)) }} // 31-12-2020
```

In **Laravel** use **Carbon** its good :

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($post->created_at)->format('d/m/Y') }} // 31/12/2020
```

See all official date format parameter  [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)